# Are Azure Subscription ID, AAD Tenant ID, and AAD App Client ID considered secret/PII?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-active-directory, telemetry, pii

I would like to log the following in my telemetry for diagnostic and usage purposes:

- Azure Subscription ID
- AAD Tenant ID
- AAD App Client ID

Should I treat them as secrets/PII and hash/encrypt them?

(it goes without saying I will not be retaining the client secret in any way shape or form)

Comment: Question should be updated to reference Entra ID instead of AAD.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Ultimately, you should determine what to log and how, from a compliance/privacy/security perspective, based on official and compliance/privacy/security reviews and certifications within your company or by 3rd parties.**

That disclaimer aside:

- **Tenant ID and App Client ID aren't generally considered PII nor secrets**.

  - Not PII because, by themselves, they won't tell you who the user is.
  - Not secrets because they are very easy to obtain. Anyone attempting to log in to your application will be exposed to these as they are included in the authorization request.
- **Azure Subscription ID isn't generally considered PII though depending on your sensitivity, could be considered a secret**

  - Not PII because, by itself, it doesn't tell you who the user is.
  - Could be a secret because it's not easily available publicly to everyone. Could be considered NOT a secret because nothing can be done with it without also having a token from an authorized user or application.

Do note that some companies and privacy reviews often consider these 3 data points as Organization Identifiable Information (OII) and sometimes have policies for handling those (less stringent that PII though).

Comment: Upvoted, thanks! (1) What if I have no organization and I'm just writing open source?  (2) What if my organization is Microsoft (I see you work there too)?

Comment: I was going to post a question on twitter/stack overflow/quora because i figured "why would anyone have answered this exact somewhat non-straight-forward question" and obviously googled first just in case - Voila. Much appreciated!

Comment: @OhadSchneider can you make this answer as the accepted answer please :)