# Which Azure parameters & keys are sensitive

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory, create-react-app, secret-key

Is there a comprehensive list over which keys and UUIDs provided by Azure are sensitive information?

For context, I am setting up a react app using [react-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal). This requires me to provide the tenantID and clientID to the app. It would be trivial for anybody with a little know-how to extract those UUIDs from the application given the way I currently have it setup. It's a static app with no back-end service, so it all runs in the browser. I have the application setup as a `App registration` (registered app?), in AzureAD to allow users to login with their Office365 account for my organization. Almost all the tutorials online show setting it up the same way I am. However, some tutorials with screenshots almost always have the clientID censored in the screenshots.

**Edit:** While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661109/are-azure-subscription-id-aad-tenant-id-and-aad-app-client-id-considered-secre) does solve my immediate need, I am in search of documentation from Microsoft concerning security best-practices in regards to Azure keys, UUIDs, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Azure Subscription ID, AAD Tenant ID, and AAD App Client ID considered secret/PII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661109/are-azure-subscription-id-aad-tenant-id-and-aad-app-client-id-considered-secre)

Comment: solves my immediate need. I was hoping to find documentation from Microsoft on it to also include all the other UUIDs and potential configuration parameters used by Azure integrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tenant ID is public and refers to the entire Azure AD directory. It must be in order to be used for authentication. You can find it [here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip153.html).

Your client app ID is not secret, as it must be used with the client secret in order to obtain a token.

Comment: So why is it censored in the link you provided if there is no concern with it being public knowledge?

Comment: Could be a screenshot from the author's company's Azure Sub? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯